# How to calculate pressure/force on a triangle vertex?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, pressure, free-body-diagram, statics

Assuming those are identical triangles. We add some weights on the upper bar. The only difference is with the location of the weights and the size of the weights. Is there any difference on the pressure that is applied on the lower point? assuming that points A,B,C are people - is it equally difficult for all of them to lift those weights? how can it be calculated/proved?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by noticing all the forces acting on your system. If your system is the triangle plus the weights, then there are two forces acting, gravity (downwards) and the force from the person. By second newton law $F_{person}-M_{Triangle Total}g=M_{Triangle Total}a_{triangle}$ thus:

$$F_{person}=M_{Triangle Total}g+M_{Triangle Total}a_{triangle}$$

and the force the person does only depends on the resulting acceleration of the triangle's motion, not on  the mass configuration.

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand the formula. can you add numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

The net downwards force in all three cases is the same- $20$kg. As pressure is force per unit area and the triangles are equivalent, it will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in terms of gravity force and pressure experienced  - no difference. However there are differences in term of torque. So if weights are big enough and rod material allows for *some bending* - you will experience such situation :

[image]

In case of (B) greater torque will summon greater bending of rod, which in turn will lower COM of rod-weights system closer to ground and also closer to a human, pushing weights, COM (pictured in scheme). Thus, *assuming bending rod material*, couple of pluses putting weights at the ends of rod (like in B picture) :

- Less risk of [Hernia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hernia#Causes) and other mechanical stress related illnesses. Because when starting to lift-up weights from the ground, rod will start to bend too. So you will feel *gradually increasing* resistance force, until weights will be in the air. So weaker human will have more time to release weights, feeling that he/she is not able to lift it. Otherwise as in case (A) you need to apply critical lifting force instantly, thus in some cases producing damage to tissues if weights are too heavy for a lifter.
- It will be more stable to keep weights in a lifted position, because now weights COM will be closer to human COM. Thus, you need less balancing with legs and so it makes feel holding weights easier to some degree.

**Again, I will repeat it depends on how easy rod material bends and how much long the rod is (weights on longer rod ends will produce greater torque)**

Comment: assuming that the rod is not bendable . we are trying to determine if there is any difference with the weights distance

Comment: My post has added value if rods are bendable. Completely ignoring torque effect makes no good to knowledge base.